# How to disable static content caching of micronaut?

Tags: java, kotlin, micronaut

I've created an application that is serving some static files, however while I'm development it's really annoying that the server caches the static content instead of returning what's on disk. And yes, using the development mode with `./gradlew run --continuous` IS sub-optimal.

I would like to know if there's a property, configuration or something that I can do to disable static content caching so that in my development profile I can set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed int he comments of the other answer, using `netty.responses.file.cache-seconds` and similar properties doesn't work 'cause that only controls the browser cache.

The problem is that when you're using `./gradlew run --continuous` and you have your `micronaut.router.static-resources.my-resources.paths` set to something like `classpath:public/`, what will happen is that micronaut, of course, will read from the classpath, which gets changed only when the build is run. In order for you take your current development version without having to rebuild your application, you should use something like:

```yaml
micronaut:
  router:
    static-resources:
      shared-static:
        enabled: true
        mapping: /public/**
        paths:
          - file:src/main/resources/public
```

By doing this in your development profile, you'll always get the latest version rendered by micronaut.

Should the browser cache **also** be a problem, then you should combine this answer with https://stackoverflow.com/a/60763922/3073044.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the cache seconds and cache control headers with

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.http.server.netty.types.files.FileTypeHandlerConfiguration

and

https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/configurationreference.html#io.micronaut.http.server.netty.types.files.FileTypeHandlerConfiguration$CacheControlConfiguration

Comment: Hello, James.

Unfortunately I didn't mention in the question, but I've tried that before: `netty.responses.file.cache-seconds: 0`

The cache header does change, however still the behavior I'm looking for doesn't happen: the application still doesn't read the file from disk again. Even renaming the file won't cause a 404 afterwards, for example. And to "stress test" that it isn't a browser cache issue, I even closed and opened another anonymous tab... still doesn't work. 

Do you think it could be a bug?

Comment: After debugging further I've found what the issue was.

It was in the `micronaut.router.static-resources.test.paths` property.

Before I had `classpath:public`, which is what I want to have in production code. 

However while developing what I should use is `file:src/main/resources/public`.

It's a bit annoying that I have to specifically configure like that, but I guess there's no other alternative, right?

thanks for the answer btw!

Comment: @Renann That is one way to go if you don't want to enable reloading globally. Its not a bug because the classpath of the application doesn't change just by changing the file. In order for that to work you would have to enable reloading